# Working with array value instances

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a simple yahtzee script in PHP, I've got up the final point where it checks the 5 dice for a result at the end.

The 5 dice sides are stored in an array, example `$dice (2,5,2,7,8)`

I'm not that experienced in working with arrays, but is there easier ways to compare each number, to like find instances of 2 the same, 3 the same, all the same etc?

`array_search()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values) might be a function that's worth looking at.  It will count the number of instances of a value in an array.

Example:

```
$dice = array(2,5,2,7,7);
$count = array_count_values($dice);

if($n = array_keys($count, 2))
{
    // 2 of a kind
    // $n = array(2, 7)
}

if(array_keys($count, 4))
{
    // 4 of a kind
}

if(array_keys($count, 2) && array_keys($count, 3))
{
    // Full House
}
```

Comment: @user1022585 - read how array_count_values() works, and that should answer your question about multiple 2 of a kinds

Comment: @user1022585:  I updated my answer which should help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Just count them.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($dice); $i++)
        $counter[$dice[$i]]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var_dump(array_count_values($array));
```